# Using a user defined type

Tags: f#, user-defined-types

I'm defining a a type to represent a board of my game:

```
type Position = (int * Piece) list
```

But when I create a list like this:

```
let board1 = [(1,Piece.BLACK);(2,Piece.WHITE);(3,Piece.BLACK);(4,Piece.WHITE);
              ...]
```

I create a list of (int * Piece) list, not a Position.

How can I change this? Which is the correct way?

E.g.:

```
val board1 : (int * Piece) list = 
[(1, BLACK); (2, WHITE); (3, BLACK); (4, WHITE);
```

Comment: See my answer here. http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/16066.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it if you wish it to use your `Position` type, otherwise it doesn't know that you want (you could easily create 5 types that are all just `(int * Piece) list`s, it wouldn't know which to choose.

You can force the type by adding `: Position` to the decleration like this:

```
type Piece = BLACK | WHITE
type Position = (int * Piece) list
let board1 : Position = [(1, BLACK); (2, WHITE); (3, BLACK); (4, WHITE); ]
```